# Cannot disable vim line break symbols

Tags: vim

I had recently updated some of the plugins in vim.After that a "**$**" sign is appearing in all the line ends of the file. I understand this is a line break issue . I added the following lines in **vimrc**

```
set wrap
set linebreak
set nolist
```

But still the **$** sign is there.

The funny part is ,if I use **set nolist** in any of the file it removes the **$** sign.
But it is not picking from **vimrc**. any solution for this?

Comment: check the output of `:verbose set list` after the `$` appears, so to figure out which plugin is enabling the list setting after loading your .vimrc file.

Answer (score 2):

The `scriptnames` command in `vim` is particularly useful for this. It shows the scripts that loaded successfully.

To show the ones that *don't* load for some reason, you can start `vim` with the `-V` option.

That should hopefully be enough for you to identify either:

- that your script is failing; or
- scripts that may load *after* your script, that could change the behaviour back with `set list`.

Comment: vim-indentguides-master is creating this issue. I removed this and the $ issue was resolved